# Vowpal Wabbit inverted_hash option produces empty output, but why?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to get a vowpal wabbit model saved with inverted hashes.  I have a valid model produced with the following:

`vw --oaa 2 -b 24 -d mydata.vw --readable_model mymodel.readable`

which produces a model file like this:

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:-1.000000
Max label:1.000000
bits:24
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options: --oaa 2
:0
66:0.016244
67:-0.016241
80:0.026017
81:-0.026020
84:0.015005
85:-0.015007
104:-0.053924
105:0.053905
112:-0.015402
113:0.015412
122:-0.025704
123:0.025704
...
```

(and so on for many thousands more features).  However, to be more useful, I need to see the feature names.  Seemed like a fairly obvious thing, but I did

`vw --oaa 2 -b 24 -d mydata.vw --invert_hash mymodel.inverted`

and it produced a model file like this (no weights are produced):

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:-1.000000
Max label:1.000000
bits:24
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options: --oaa 2
:0
```

It feels like I've obviously done something wrong, but I think I'm using the options in the [documented way](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments):

> `--invert_hash` is similar to `--readable_model`, but the model is output in a more human readable format with feature names followed by
>   weights, instead of hash indexes and weights.

Does anyone see why my second command is failing to produce any output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in VW which was fixed recently (on account of this question), see https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/337.

By the way, it does not make sense to use `--oaa 2`. If you want binary classification (aka logistic regression), use `--loss_function=logistic` (and make sure your labels are 1 and -1).
OAA makes sense only for N>2 number of classes (and it is recommended to use `--loss_function=logistic` with `--oaa`).

Also note that learning with `--invert_hash` is **much slower** (and requires more memory, of course). The recommended way how to create inverted-hash model, especially with multiple passes, is to learn a usual binary model and then convert it to inverted hash using one pass over the training data with `-t`:

```
vw -d mytrain.data -c --passes 4 -oaa 3 -f model.binary
vw -d mytrain.data -t -i model.binary --invert_hash model.humanreadable
```

Comment: Interesting.  Experimentally, I find results that could be interpreted to disagree with your point about `--oaa`.  With only `-b 31`, it reports an average loss of .6.  With `-b 31 --loss_function=logistic`, it reports a loss of .48 (and fiddling with `-l` and `--l1` and `--passes` don't really change it much). With `-b 31 --oaa 2 -c -k --passes 3 -l 0.25`, vw reports only a loss of .19.  If `--oaa 2` doesn't make sense, then why does it perform so much better?  I'm not trying to be disagreeable; I just want to understand.

Comment: You should not compare apples (0/1 loss) and oranges (logistic or square loss). For OAA, VW reports always 0/1 loss. Without OAA (or other multiclass reductions), VW reports the loss you asked for (square, logistic, hinge...).

Comment: You can force VW to report 0/1 loss for binary classification with `--binary`.

Comment: I admit `--oaa 2` can give sometimes **slightly** better results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674880/effect-of-oaa-2-and-loss-function-logistic-in-vowpal-wabbit

Comment: Hmm, ok.  if I use `--loss_function=logistic --binary` together, it produces results very similar to what `--oaa 2` produces.

Comment: I do `vw -d train.data -c --passes 10 --loss_function=logistic -f model.binary` This works. Then I do `vw -d train.data -t -i model.binary --invert_hash model.humanreadable`. I get this error `unrecognized options: --invert_hash model.humanreadable
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
  what():  std::exception
Aborted (core dumped).