# Effect of --oaa 2 and --loss_function=logistic in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

What parameters should I use in VW for a binary classification task? For example, let's use [rcv1_small.dat](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/test/train-sets/rcv1_small.dat). I [thought](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Loss-functions#which-loss-function-should-i-use) it is better to use the logistic loss function (or hinge) and it makes no sense to use `--oaa 2`. However, the empirical results (with progressive validation 0/1 loss reported in all 4 experiments) show that best combination is `--oaa 2` without logistic loss (i.e. with the default squared loss):

```
cd vowpal_wabbit/test/train-sets

cat rcv1_small.dat | vw --binary
# average loss = 0.0861

cat rcv1_small.dat | vw --binary --loss_function=logistic
# average loss = 0.0909

cat rcv1_small.dat | sed 's/^-1/2/' | vw --oaa 2
# average loss = 0.0857

cat rcv1_small.dat | sed 's/^-1/2/' | vw --oaa 2 --loss_function=logistic
# average loss = 0.0934
```

My primary question is: **Why `--oaa 2` does not give exactly the same results as `--binary`** (in the above setting)**?**

My secondary questions are: Why optimizing the logistic loss does not improve the 0/1 loss (compared to optimizing the default square loss)? Is this a specific of this particular dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced something similar while using `--csoaa`. The details could be found [here](http://www.kaggle.com/c/tradeshift-text-classification/forums/t/10518/random-forest-benchmark/57313#post57313). My guess is that in case of multiclass problem with N classes (no matter that you specified 2 as a number of classes) vw virtually works with N copies of features. Same example gets different ft_offset value when it's predicted/learned for every possible class and this offset is used in hashing algorithm. So all classes get "independent" set of features from same dataset's row. Of course feature values are same, but vw doesn't keep values - only feature weights. And weights are different for each possible class. And as amount of RAM used for storing these weights is fixed with `-b` (`-b 18` by default) - the more classes you have the more chance to get a hash collision. You can try to increase `-b` value and check if difference between `--oaa 2` and `--binary` results is decreasing. But I might be wrong as I didn't go too deep into the vw code.

As for loss function - you can't compare avg loss values of squared (default) and logistic loss functions directly. You shall get raw prediction values from result obtained with squared loss and get loss of these predictions in terms of logistic loss. The function will be: `log(1 + exp(-label * prediction)` where label is a priori known answer. Such functions (`float getLoss(float prediction, float label)` ) for all loss functions implemented in vw could be found in [loss_functions.cc](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/loss_functions.cc). Or you can preliminary scale raw prediction value to [0..1] with `1.f / (1.f + exp(- prediction)` and then calc log loss as described on [kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss) :

```
double val = 1.f / (1.f + exp(- prediction); // y = f(x) -> [0, 1]
if (val < 1e-15) val = 1e-15;
if (val > (1.0 - 1e-15)) val = 1.0 - 1e-15;
float xx = (label < 0)?0:1; // label {-1,1} -> {0,1}
double loss = xx*log(val) + (1.0 - xx) * log(1.0 - val);
loss *= -1;
```

You can also scale raw predictions to [0..1] with '/vowpal_wabbit/utl/logistic' script or `--link=logistic` parameter. Both use `1/(1+exp(-i))`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer for my primary question seems to be correct. Adding `-b 28` to the examples above results in squared=0.0856, logistic=0.0909, oaa_squared=0.0855, oaa_logistic=0.0909. Interestingly, with the hash collisions (with the default -b 18), oaa (with twice as many features) is sometimes (squared) better, sometimes (logistic) worse.

Comment: As for my secondary question, I am not comparing squared vs. logistic loss values. All the values reported are 0/1 loss. For binary classification, this is the effect of `--binary` (btw: it has no effect on the final model/weights). For oaa, reporting 0/1 loss (i.e., 1 minus accuracy) is the default (which cannot be changed, e.g. to multiclass-logistic loss). So I think my secondary question is still unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you're compare 0/1 loss over raw predictions from 2 diff loss functions. I'm currently working with modified vw sources where 0/1 loss is replaced in `--oaa` with average log loss as required by current kaggle competition. I could try with original sources next week.

Comment: Till that I would guess following. As loss function define not only loss value but also a step that is need to be made in a generic gradient descent algorithm and as vw is online-learning system - it's matter how fast the algorithm converge with specific loss function. Also as you're measuring final average loss it might depend on dataset size. If dataset is small it's matter how gd with certain loss function behave on very first steps where predictions are close to 50/50.

Comment: This uncertainty period might be bigger with logloss and its impact is amplified after conversion to 0/1 loss.
I would try to specify `--passes n ` and hope that on longer distance the results become expectable.

Comment: You are right again, `vw --binary -c --loss_function=logistic --passes=2` results in loss "0.077 h". It is a holdout loss, so it is not truly comparable to values reported before (as now I'm training on 90% of the data only). However, `--loss_function=logistic` results in the same loss "0.077 h", so it seems that two passes helped to hide the difference between logistic and squared loss. More passes did almost no difference. The same holds for `--oaa`. So I consider my question fully answered. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using more passes, I can also tune the initial learning rate. `vw --binary --loss_function=logistic -l 1` results in 0.0885. Due to recent VW improvements, `vw --binary` has now 0.0856. And the optimal learning rate: `vw --binary -l 0.45` has 0.0852. So with tuned learning rate, the gap between logistic and squared is a bit smaller even for one pass (but it is still there). OK, I'm finished with this nitpicking.